# MySQL increment value in a text field

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a text field with JSON data like this:

```
{
    "id": {
        "name": "value",
        "votes": 0
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write a query which would find `id` and then would increment `votes` value?

I know i could just retrieve the JSON data update what I need and reinsert updated version, but i wonder is there a way to do this without running two queries?

Comment: There isn't any easy or efficient way to do that. If you have the need for that, then relational database isn't for you.

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL?  Is the data stored in a database?

Comment: @N.B. Yes i know that this is a stupid way to do this, but this is something that wont be used often and it would increase performance of other things that im doing.

Comment: You could define a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) in the database.

Comment: You know that you'd have to manipulate the string in some way after finding the record. I don't know whether any RDBMS has some sort of JSON functionality so you'd have to do this manually - which is neither fun or easy, and it's definitely prone to errors. It's questionable whether you'd get any sort of performance if you did it on database level, you'd probably reduce the network footprint but we're talking about milliseconds here because even the DB has to update the record after manipulating the string. Same as if you did what you had to in some language and then sent it back to DB.

Comment: @N.B. I see, well then I should rethink my approach to the problem I'm facing, thanks.

Comment: You won't lose too much if you fetch the record, json_decode (or whatever you use), increment the value and send it back for update. On the other hand, document-based databases do this kind of thing natively so they might be a better choice (MongoDB for example).

Comment: It certainly doable, but either painful or fun depending on your level of masochism.  I think the steps would be: REGEX to find values, cast vote string as int, increment, convert all back to string.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE `sometable`
    SET `somefield` = JSON_REPLACE(`somefield`, '$.id.votes', JSON_EXTRACT(`somefield` , '$.id.votes')+1)
    WHERE ...
```

**Edit**

[As of MySQL 5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), MySQL supports a native JSON data type that enables efficient access to data in JSON documents.

[JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) will allow you to access a particular JSON element in a JSON field, while [JSON_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace) will allow you to update it.

To specify the JSON element you wish to access, use a string with the format

```
'$.[top element].[sub element].[...]'
```

So in your case, to access **id.votes**, use the string **'$.id.votes'**.

The SQL code above demonstrates putting all this together to increment the value of a JSON field by 1.

Comment: Please explain why you think this code helps the OP. This will help both the OP and future visitors.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think for a task like this you're stuck using a plain old `SELECT` followed by an `UPDATE` (after you parse the JSON, increment the value you want, and then serialize the JSON back).

You should wrap these operations in a single transaction, and if you're using InnoDB then you might also consider using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

This is sort of a tangent, but I thought I'd also mention that this is the type of operation that a NoSQL database like MongoDB is quite good at.